# Local storage using OpenUI5 and Apache Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, sapui5

I'm building a mobile app using OpenUI5 and Cordova. This app consume OData services but must support full offline capabilities. There are many optiones to store data using Cordova such as LocalStorage, Web SQL or even FileWriter. Also I find that OpenUI5 framework offer jQuery.sap.storage to store data through LocalStorage but I can't take this option into account due to the limited storage capacity (5MB).

Is it possible to request the entire data model from the OData service and convert it into JSON model? Because if there is any way to accomplish this, I could write files for every entity in the model (and the metadata file) using the FileWriter and consume this model when the app goes offline.

Does anyone tried to do something like this?

**Edited**

Thanks for answering...

I'm using jumpifzero tips to set data from the OData services into the Json model, like this:

```
    var sServiceUrl = "http://address:port/DataService.svc/";       
    var odataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, true);
    var jsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

    odataModel.read("/Dates", {
        async: false,
        success: function (odata, response) {
            jsonModel.setData({ Dates: odata.results });
        }
    });

    this.setModel(jsonModel);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also read the odata for each entityset, with the .read method, without any filter. In the success function given to the read, you can put the JS objects in a JSON model.
You can make a layer that fills the JSON model from the odata when online and from localstorage when offline.

Answer (score 0):

You have an option to create offline apps (CRUD) using offline Kapsel plugin (Cordova plugin developed by SAP) that comes with SAP Mobile Platform. You should buy license for SAP Mobile Platform.
You can find more information here: http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-58063

Answer (score 0):

I don't suggest offline Kapsel plugin. It is not mature enough to use it and it is actually under development. Furthermore you would need an SMP server for offline feature.
I would rather say you should use a half-baked solution that you form according your needs e.g.: http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/05/simple-offline-data-synchronization-for-mobile-web-and-phonegap-applications/